# Ubuntu uninstall

Tags: mac, apple

Hi all I have a 2009 i7 iMac with abuntu
I power on iMac ,then get 1st screen white no apple logo
then I get purple screen
Given me options for
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Ubuntu 21.10 (21.10) (on /dev/sda3)
Advanced options for Ubuntu 21.10 (21.10) (on/dev/sda3

I brought this iMac with ubuntu installed
I don’t want ubuntu as the os for this iMac can someone help me remove for this iMac permanently please
I don’t understand anything about ubuntu
I need apple os back on I need to remove Ubuntu any help
Regards
Abdulrashid

Comment: Installing MacOS is off topic. Review support options for Apple/Mac.

Comment: Get an installation media for the OS (USB, DVD) you want to install, boot it up and follotw instructions. You will want to use the whole disk / overwrite disk for the new OS.

Answer (score 2):

You don't *uninstall* an Operating System.

You *overwrite* with a new Operating System. Insert and boot an OSX installer. It will overwrite Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi I need help getting apple high Sierra installed

Comment: See paragraph 2: "*Insert and boot an OSX installer*" If you need more help than that, please be specific.

Comment: Hi I don’t have osx installer any idea where I can get item from ?

Comment: Wrong place to ask. Ask in a Mac support venue. We can tell you where to find an Ubuntu installer.